# Spring JPA - inserting double value without exponential value

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a spring boot project with JPA where i am facing an issue.

From UI i will get a string of 4 length and i have to append 4 zeros as prefix and save it in a table. The data type of this column in entity is Double.

eg, String from UI is 1234, then i have to make it as 0.00001234 and insert into a table.

```
Double d = new Double("0.00001234");
```

after inserting into table, i can see the value is inserted as 1.234E-5. But i want to insert the value as 0.00001234.

Worst case, if we cannot insert as 0.00001234, is there a way where i can get the 1.234E-5 value from db and get just the last 4 digits from that value and send it back to UI as string? I tried DecimalFormat formatting but not exactly getting what i want.

Also i cannot change the data type as BigDecimal since lot of other code also use this entity.

Thanks.

Comment: `1.234E-5` is just the display format. The underlying data is still `0.00001234` which you will also get back if you perform a request

Comment: Just for clarification, you're inserting a double via JPA into a relational database, and if you take a look at the database's table, let's say using an SQL client like 'MySQL Workbench' or 'Data Grip', the number is displayed in this format `1.234E-5`. What's the problem? It's just how the SQL client displays it. If you fetch this number later on again via JPA you can display it without scientific notation.

Comment: Even if its a lot of work, I recommend you consider a change form Double to BigDecimal/Decimal. In my current work, we deal with money and a lot of operations including taxes and such. Our models use Double, but we found how troublesome sometimes it can be to work with it. We had to program a whole math layer that takes Double as input, "cast" them to BigDecimal, do the math and return it as a Double truncated for the cents to avoid errors. I suspect your case needs more precision, so yeah, please at least consider it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this in java

BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("1.234E-5");

String number=bd.toString();
This will convert bigDEcimal to String.

System.out.println(bd);

It will give you output like this 0.00001234

Answer (score 0):

String.format("%,.8f", d);
this will convert your double 1.234E-5 to string "0.00001234".